# Web Services Copy.asmx(copyintoitems) - copy attach(base64binary) to Sharepoint library from infopath

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, attachment, infopath2010, data-connections

I need to copy an attach(base64binary) from a form infopath to sharepoint library without code. So, I follow next tutorial like example of use. [here](http://m4sh3d.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/how-to-upload-infopath-2010-attachments.html)

This tutorial use a Web services Copy.asmx(Copyintoitems) to copy files between sites Sharepoint from infopath. This link shows complete details.[here](http://m4sh3d.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/how-to-upload-infopath-2010-attachments.html)

The file is correctly copied to Document library in Sharepoint. The problem is when I try to open the file copied. Then, I receive next error message. "The file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents". After, I receive other dialog with this message "Word found unreadable content in name.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document. If you trust the source of the document, click Yes". When I click on "Yes" I can see the content correctly.

Nevertheless, if I copy the document word from a file compressed .rar/.zip. The file opens correctly in Sharepoint library.

Please, Somebody could help me with this issue because I don't understand why every word document is copied as if it was corrupted.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Roberto.